# Jumping on canvas

Tags: javascript

I can't figure out how I can make myGamePiece jump using the up-key. First I tried the simple "myGamePiece.speedY = 1", but this doesn't work. Nor does trying to reverse "this.gravitySpeed" in the function. Can someone help me and if possible explain why mine don't work and yours does? Thanks in advance! My excuses if it seems to long, I'm unable to shorten it even further without removing the code of the component.

A litle explaination for the code:

function startGame: Starts the game

var myGameArea: Allows to multiply press two keys

function component: generates the object and its characteristics

function updateGameArea: Allows for the movement of the object

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
    <style>
    canvas {
        border:1px solid #d3d3d3;
        background-color: #f1f1f1;
    }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body onload="startGame()">
    <script>
    var myGamePiece;

function startGame() {
    myGamePiece = new component(30, 30, "red", 80, 75);
    myGameArea.start();
}

var myGameArea = {
    canvas : document.createElement("canvas"),
    start : function() {
        this.context = this.canvas.getContext("2d");
        document.body.insertBefore(this.canvas, document.body.childNodes[0]);
        this.interval = setInterval(updateGameArea, 20);
        window.addEventListener('keydown', function (e) {
            myGameArea.keys = (myGameArea.keys || []);
            myGameArea.keys[e.keyCode] = true;
        })
        window.addEventListener('keyup', function (e) {
            myGameArea.keys[e.keyCode] = false; 
        })
    }, 
    clear : function() {
        this.context.clearRect(0, 0, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height);
    }
}

function component(width, height, color, x, y, type) {
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;    
    this.gravity = 0.05;
    this.gravitySpeed = 0;
    this.update = function() {
        ctx = myGameArea.context;
        ctx.fillStyle = color;
        ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
    }
    this.newPos = function() {
        this.gravitySpeed += this.gravity;
        this.x += this.speedX;
        this.y += this.speedY + this.gravitySpeed;
        this.hitBottom();
    }
    this.hitBottom = function() {
        var rockbottom = myGameArea.canvas.height - this.height;
        if (this.y > rockbottom) {
            this.y = rockbottom;
        }
    }
}

function updateGameArea() {
myGameArea.clear();
    myGamePiece.speedX = 0;
    myGamePiece.speedY = 0; 
    if (myGameArea.keys && myGameArea.keys[37]) {myGamePiece.speedX = -2; }
    if (myGameArea.keys && myGameArea.keys[39]) {myGamePiece.speedX = 2; }
    if (myGameArea.keys && myGameArea.keys[38]) {myGamePiece.speedY = -1; }
    if (myGameArea.keys && myGameArea.keys[40]) {myGamePiece.speedY = 1; }
    myGamePiece.newPos(); 
    myGamePiece.update();
}
    </script>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Why do we need to see all this code? Please provide an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I have shortened the code a bit, but I'm unable to shorten it even further

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the value of the `gravitySpeed` variable is constantly increasing.

Try to reset the `gravitySpeed` variable value to 0 in your `hitBottom` check:

```
if (this.y > rockbottom) {
    this.y = rockbottom;
    this.gravitySpeed = 0;
}
```

You may also want to view values of some parameters in real time while you debugging:

add a block like this to your html

```
<div style="position:absolute; width: 300px; bottom: 50px; right: 50px;">
    <p>sppedY: <span id="speedY"></span></p>
    <p>gravitySpeed: <span id="gravitySpeed"></span></p>
    <p>posY: <span id="posY"></span></p>
</div>
```

and a block like this in your updateGameArea function

```
...
myGamePiece.newPos();

// -- debug --
speedY.innerText = myGamePiece.speedY.toFixed(2);
gravitySpeed.innerText = myGamePiece.gravitySpeed.toFixed(2);
posY.innerText = myGamePiece.y.toFixed(2);
// -----------

myGamePiece.update();
```

Comment: I was even able to change the jumping height, thank you so much!